# network server mode vs embedded mode in JavaDB

Tags: java, database, derby

I am trying to develop a desktop application to be run on local network. It has two UI. One for users to log in complaints and another one to process the complaints. Both of them are connected to a single database. Now i want to know weather i should use the JavaDB in embedded mode or network server mode to implement this and what is the difference between the two approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In embedded mode the database code runs in the same process as the embedding application. The database files are locked, no other process can access the database files. This is the right choice if you have only one application with one user per database. The advantage over network mode is that there is no network traffic to access the database.

In network mode the database code runs in its own process (the database server). Client applications can access the database over the network. Several client applications can access the database at the same time. So this should be the right choice for you, because you have two different client applications accessing the database at the same time.